# Passing arguments, does unboxing occur

Tags: c#, .net

What I have read, passing arguments is by default valuetypes. In my example the first function test1 takes a reference type and unbox, it will decrease the performance if I got this right. 
However I have never read that you do like test2 for increase performance.

So whats best practice?

```
public Main(){
    string test = "hello";
    test1(test); // Does this line perform a boxing? So it's not good for performance?
    test2(ref test); // Passing a reference as a reference
}

public string test1(string arg1) {
    return arg1;
}

public string test2(ref string arg1) {
    return arg1;
}
```

Comment: As I understand, boxing only refers to value types. `String` is not a value type.

Comment: Am I wrong that unboxing refers to String that is reference is treated as a valuetype?

Comment: @SimonEdström. +1. yes, you're wrong... =)

Comment: I think you've conflated two concepts - there are (value types and reference types) and (passing by value and passing by reference). The two concepts are completely distinct. Boxing/Unboxing are related to when value types are treated as reference types.

Comment: If you changed all the `string` in the example to, say, `int` or `float`, then the question might make more sense (`string` is not a value-type, so boxing doesn't even apply) - but no: it still wouldn't be boxed; boxing **only** happens when treating as a reference type, i.e. if `arg` was `object` or an interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no boxing or unboxing involved at all here. `string` is a reference type - why would it be boxed? What would that even mean?

Even if you used `int` instead, there'd be no need for boxing, because there's no conversion of the value into an actual object.

I suspect your understanding of both [boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) and [parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) is flawed.

Boxing occurs when a value type value needs to be converted into an object, usually in order for it to be used as a variable (somewhere) of an interface or object type. So *this* boxes:

```
int value = 10;
Foo(value);

...

public void Foo(object x)
{
}
```

... but it *wouldn't* occur if `Foo` were changed such that the type of `x` were `int` instead.

The detailed rules on boxing become very complicated to state precisely and accurately, particularly where generics come in, but that's the basics.

Answer (score 5):

There is no boxing here at all; boxing is when a value type is treated as `object` or an interface (not including generics), for example:

```
int i = 1;
Foo(i); // the value of i is boxed
Bar(i); // the value of i is boxed
...
private void Foo(object obj) {...}
private void Bar(IConvertible obj) {...}
```

In your examples, a: there is no type conversion here, so no need to box, and b: `string` is a reference-type anyway, so there is no *meaning* of boxing a string.

Your `test2` is actually showing "pass by reference", aka `ref`, which is completely unrelated to boxing - and indeed `ref` parameters must be an **exact** match, so there is **never** any boxing involved in a `ref` parameter (however, subsequent code could obtain the value *from* the reference and then box/unbox *that*)

Comment: Thanks! I was a bit lost and confused